# Scala - expand a list of various types while keeping the same types

Tags: scala, types, list-manipulation

I have a List with various types like so:

`val data: List[(String, Int, List[String])] = List(("foo", 1, List("a", "b")), ("bar", 2, List("c", "d")), ("baz", 1, List("e", "f")))`

Where there is an Int value large than 1, I am trying to replicate those items for each Int in that range (from 1 to Int) - so ideally it would look like (*emphasizing that the Int needs to be incremented for each iteration from 1 to Int*):

`val dataExpanded: List[(String, Int, List[String])] = List(("foo", 1, List("a", "b")), ("bar", 1, List("c", "d")), ("bar", 2, List("c", "d")), ("baz", 1, List("e", "f")))`

Working with types in scala routinely does my head in, particularly with nested strucutures since every operation seems to introduce more and more type pitfalls.

So while I am trying:

```
val dataExpanded = data.map{ case (s, i, l) =>

    if (i > 1) {

        List.range(1, i+1).map { n =>
            (s, n, l)
        }

    } else {
        (s, i, l)
    }
}
```

I get the result:

`> dataExpanded: List[Product with java.io.Serializable] = List((foo,1,List(a, b)), List((bar,1,List(c, d)), (bar,2,List(c, d))), (baz,1,List(e, f)))`

The result looks like it is on the right path, but the expanded elements are nested in their own list and, as a result, I think, the Type is wrong. no amount of flatMapping or flattening or mapping the output of the for loop is getting me out of this jam.

This might also have to do with my case statement and not handling a None case, but I am not sure how to handle the other cases (I know it's not right to say, but I won't really have any other cases in my data - though that's the inebriation of dynamically typed languages talking)

Is there a way to maintain the expected types when going from `data` to `dataExpanded` while avoiding needless loops?

Comment: The problem is that the types are different in the two branches of the if/else (with [stricter compiler arguments](http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/04/11/scalac-flags.html) this would be an error, which might have helped you find the problem). You could make the `else` branch `List((s, i, l))` and then you'd just have to `flatten`. Though as you can see from the suggestions, you don't really need the `if`/`else` at all - the code in the `if` branch works fine even when `i=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you could have done

```
val dataExpanded = data.flatMap {
case (s, i, l) =>
  List.range(1, i + 1).map { n =>
    (s, n, l)
  }
 }                                               

//> dataExpanded  : List[(String, Int, List[String])] = List((foo,1,List(a, b)),
                        (bar,1,List(c, d)), (bar,2,List(c, d)), (baz,1,List(e, f)))
```

Or more neatly as

```
val dataExpanded = data.flatMap {
    case (s, i, l) =>
      (1 to i).map ((s, _, l))
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider case classes for the tuples, like this

```
case class Datum(s: String, n: Int, xs: List[String])
```

and thus given

```
val data: List[Datum] = List(Datum("foo", 1, List("a", "b")), 
                             Datum("bar", 2, List("c", "d")), 
                             Datum("baz", 1, List("e", "f")))
```

we can use the `copy` method in case classes as follows,

```
def expand(d: Datum) = (1 to d.n).map (i => d.copy(n=i))
```

which *copies* the fields contents and modifies specified fields, in this case `n`. Hence for `data`,

```
data.flatMap(expand(_))
```

delivers the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A little more verbose than @enzyme answer but here is an approach with recursion, pattern matching, and a for expression to generate the `List` of tuples.

```
def expand(xs: List[Tuple3[String, Int, List[String]]]): List[Tuple3[String,Int, List[String]]] = xs match {
 case Nil => Nil
 case h :: t => if (h._2 == 1) 
                  h :: expand(t)
                else
                  (for(i <- 1 to h._2) yield (h._1, i, h._3)).toList ++ expand(t)
}
```

Outputs:

```
scala> expand(data)
List[(String, Int, List[String])] = List((foo,1,List(a, b)), (bar,1,List(c, d)), (bar,2,List(c, d)), (baz,1,List(e, f)))
```